# delete previous migration on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration, web-deployment

I have a Ruby on Rails application.  I changed my database and I want to deploy it to heroku.

How can I delete previous migrations on heroku and migrate my new database design?

I test using this code: `heroku run db:migrate`, but when I want to create a object from my new database design I got this error: `We're sorry, but something went wrong`

However, when I refresh my page it was created!  What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's your database? Try running `heroku logs -t` and running the request again. Then check your log and post your results. It might not even be a database problem.

To erase your database run

```
heroku pg:reset --db SHARED_DATABASE_URL
```

or

```
heroku pg:reset --db SHARED_DATABASE
```

then run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

If all your migrations are correct then you should not experience the same problem.

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `image_address' for #<Product:0x00000002b5f6d8>):  but it's work perfectly in my local system !!!!

Comment: Are you sure you created the migrations in the right order using the Rails generators? If it works on your local system then the migrations should probably run correctly in heroku. Updating my answer with a solution.

Comment: tnx alot man. I use your advice and this **heroku pg:reset DATABASE** it works.